Debugging a language model from "Deep Learning with Python"
I'm trying to run the language modeling notebook from Deep Learning with Python (https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter12_part01_text-generation.ipynb). Note: I changed one thing in the notebook, tf.math.not_equal(inputs, 0) -> layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.not_equal(x, 0))(inputs)
The book claims that after 200 epochs of training, the model works. It says some "cherrypicked examples" of what the model can generate are, e.g.

“this movie is a [UNK] of the original movie and the first half hour of the
movie is pretty good but it is a very good movie it is a good movie for the time
period”

When I run it, after about 10 epochs of training the model is grossly overfit and generates stuff like

This movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie  movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie movie  movie movie movie  movie  movie

In addition, from epoch 12 -> 13 the loss goes from ~3.5 -> ~0.3, suggesting the model found some discrete trick it's now using.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm running this using an A100 on google colab.
